# Why difference is different between terms of an arithmetic progression?

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

Find the common difference of the arithmetic progression $\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{27}, \sqrt{48}, \dots$

When I try to find the difference between the first and second term I end up with $2\sqrt{3}$, but when I try between the second and third terms, I end up with $\sqrt{3}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, it simply isn't an arithmetic progression because the difference is not common. Where did you get such a question from?

Comment: From my book. And this question is from Sequence and Series chapter's A.P. Section. But as you said it's not an A.P. at all.

Comment: Does your book have a name?

Comment: I don't think it has, because it's specific in my University. They have their own courses.

Comment: Oh, they skipped the second term $\sqrt{12}$ in printing but there's no gap between. I think so. lol